# How to sum the values of all rows in a column that has been dynamically generated?

Tags: c#, sql, itext, datarow

Good Morning Fellow Coders,

I am trying to Sum all values in each row of a specific Column called `SubTotal`
SubTotal needs to sum from the `LineTotal` of every row, but the rows are generated dynamically and on a button click event. I will link my code down below and a screen shot and maybe one of you can help me:

EDIT: - I have tried all the "Solutions" below but each time i try to add that to my page it makes it that my PDF has no pages, i have tried doing my own research too, to no avail as those also make it that my pdf has no pages

tried these:-

```
(1)int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Salary)", string.Empty));

(2)DataTable dt= dataSet.Tables["YourTableName"];
object lineTotalInputSum ;
lineTotalInputSum = dt.Compute("Sum("YourColumnName")", string.Empty);

(3)var subTotal= rows.Sum(row => row.Field<double>("LineTotal"));
```

i am not saying any of you are wrong, i am saying that i am not sure how to implement these suggestions into my code and keep the rest working, if you could give me a simple explanation i will do my best to make it work, feel free to ask for any additional code that i have not provided

------END EDIT--------

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{                     
    //Adding dt.Rows to Strings for Use in iTextSharp
    string lineNumberInput = dataRow[1].ToString();
    string itemCodeInput = dataRow[12].ToString();
    string itemNameInput = dataRow[13].ToString();
    string QtyInput = dataRow[14].ToString();
    string UnitPriceInput = dataRow[15].ToString();
    //string Discount = dt.Rows[0][""].ToString();
    string lineTotalInput = dataRow[16].ToString();
    string wasReturnedInput = dataRow[17].ToString();

    //Implementing strings in iTextSharp
    var Cell_LineNumberList = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase(lineNumberInput, tablefont));
    var Cell_ItemCodelist = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase(itemCodeInput, tablefont));
    var Cell_ItemNamelist = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase(itemNameInput, tablefont));
    var Cell_Qtylist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(QtyInput, 
    tablefont));
    var Cell_UnitPricelist = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase(UnitPriceInput, tablefont));
    var Cell_Discountlist = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase("None", tablefont));
    var Cell_LineTotallist = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase(lineTotalInput, tablefont));
    var Cell_WasReturnedlist = new PdfPCell(new 
    Phrase(wasReturnedInput, tablefont));

    //Aligning all the cells
    Cell_LineNumberList.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_ItemCodelist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_ItemNamelist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_Qtylist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_UnitPricelist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_Discountlist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_LineTotallist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Cell_WasReturnedlist.HorizontalAlignment = 
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


    //adding the cells to the table
    t.AddCell(Cell_LineNumberList);
    t.AddCell(Cell_ItemCodelist);
    t.AddCell(Cell_ItemNamelist);
    t.AddCell(Cell_Qtylist);
    t.AddCell(Cell_UnitPricelist);
    t.AddCell(Cell_Discountlist);
    t.AddCell(Cell_LineTotallist);
    t.AddCell(Cell_WasReturnedlist);
}
```

Below you will find a screen shot of the column I want to sum in red and the value(from where the values come) column in green * these are all dynamically generated*

[image]

If you can just show me how to store it in a var then i can take it from there 
and thank you in advance.

Comment: You should search the web for `c# linq datarow sum`, you'll find plenty of answers.

Comment: thank you ill give that a shot, ill keep an eye here too just incase i dont come right

Comment: Hi Aybe, i came accross this which i think could work but i dont understand

    ```int sum = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sum += (int)dr[dc];
                }
            } ```


this dc is every datacolumn? how could i make it that its only the subtotal column

Comment: Yes it does, you might want to adjust it. (check answer below for an alternative)

Comment: please see my edit on post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how your DataTable looks like but you use the [Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method to get the sum of the column that you want:

```
DataTable dt= dataSet.Tables["YourTableName"];
object lineTotalInputSum ;
lineTotalInputSum = dt.Compute("Sum("YourColumnName")", string.Empty);
```

Comment: @devandholmes What error do you get when you use this solution? Use `try-catch` blocks and debug the code to see where exactly the error is occurring. Also make sure you are passing the correct column name here: `dt.Compute("Sum("YourColumnName")", string.Empty);`

Comment: i dont get a compile time error, i get an error that says your pdf document has no pages on the button click event that generates the pdf, ill run debug now and see where i am going wrong- i rate my debug skills 6/10

Comment: and also in 

   DataTable dt= dataSet.Tables["YourTableName"];
object lineTotalInputSum ;
lineTotalInputSum = dt.Compute("Sum("YourColumnName")", string.Empty);

the first line that says DataTable dt = ... i have already declared my datatable so do i need to do this again

Comment: @devandholmes Okay, let me know what you see and No you do not need to declare the data table again. Use your original data table `dt`

Comment: you kind sir are a Star, i figured out where i was going wrong and it was all to do with my "value extraction"

the object returns as a float and i was passing straight to a string without first converting to string, once i said . ToString() like a smart person would of remembered to do , everything started working again and i got the result i was looking for, i thank you greatly for your time and i give the Answer to you

Comment: @devandholmes Glad to hear that you got it working sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the LINQ on the "Line Total" Column outside your foreach loop as follows

```
var subTotal= rows.Sum(row => row.Field<double>("LineTotal"));
```

or as you are processing row by row, use a old school method of having a variable and adding the row values to it.

Hope this helps!